# How to connect to remote server using linux ssh tunel command

Tags: linux, ssh, tunneling, manjaro

I have an easy-one here, I'm new using linux to connect to other linux server, the issue is that on a remote server which I can reach from my vpn, I have a GUI running on the port `x.x.x.x:6500`

I did not have any problem using putty/xshell to make a tunnel to the server and then to see the GUI in my laptop using the `localhost:6500`.

I'm trying to do the same on my Manjaro VM but I'm having troubles to see the GUI since there. The page says connection refused...

I'm using the following command:

```
$ ssh -L 6500:127.0.0.1:6500 x.x.x.x -v
```

Maybe the command is wrong, that's not the correct syntax?

Comment: "connection refused" generally means the service listener isn't running.  Q: Have you installed and enabled the ssh service?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. the conection refused is not in the ssh connection because Iḿ able to connect to the server sicne the command line, but when I do the tunnel and the access is OK, then I go to the web browser and there is were i got the connection refused

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  or [unix.se], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi All, I found the way to do properly a tunnel. Hope it will work for you
ssh user@server.example.com -L 2409:X.X.X.X:6500